# Universal Image Loader and loading distinct Image Strings

Tags: java

I am currently working off of this open source:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

I'm trying to adjust the names Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, etc to name each individual picture.
I'm also trying to create a set of image urls for say listview.  In addition, a set of separate distinct image urls for gridview.  Therefore, when a user clicks on listview there will be certain urls and when gridview is pressed, there will be images that have never been seen before.

Any help dissecting the code is greatly appreciated as I am a new programmer.

So far, I understand how to change the current url images in "String IMAGES" but am having a tough time creating a new list of url images described above.

Comment: Any help?  I've been trying to dissect the code with still no luck.  Thanks.

Comment: I was able to understand how to add new images.  Unfortunately, I can not add sounds to the items that I choose from ListView.  Nor can I rename each item (i.e. Item 1 = IC_Logo).